# Is there a "Group Box" equivalent in Java Swing?

Tags: java, swing, grouping

Trying to build a GUI application in Java/Swing. I'm mainly used to "painting" GUIs on the Windows side with tools like VB (or to be more precise, Gupta SQLWindows... wonder how many people know what that is ;-)).

I can't find an equivalent of a Group Box in Swing...

With a group box, you have a square box (usually with a title) around a couple of related widgets. One example is a group box around a few radio buttons (with the title explaining what the radio buttons are about, e.g. Group Box entitled "Sex" with "Male" and "Female" radio buttons).

I've searched around a bit... the only way I found was to add a sub-pane, set the border on the sub-pane and then add all the widgets in the "group" to the sub-pane. Is there a more elegant way to do that?

Comment: Perhaps you could explain what a group box is.

Comment: I think he means the control group you see in many dialog boxes, where you have a square around a bunch of widgets such as radio buttons, for example.

Answer (score 120, accepted):

Create a JPanel, and add your radiobuttons to it.  Don't forget to set the layout of the JPanel to something appropriate.

Then call `panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(name));`

Answer (score 8):

Others have already commetned about JPanel and using a TitledBorder, that's fine.

However, when playing with Swing LayoutManagers, you may find it annoying that components in different JPanels cannot align correctly (each panel has its own LayoutManager).

For this reason, it is a good practice (check "JGoodies" on the web for more details) in Swing GUIs to NOT use TitledBorders but rather separate groups of components in a JPanel by a JLabel followed by a horizontal JSeparator.

Ref. "[First Aid for Swing](http://www.jgoodies.com/download/presentations/first%20aid%20for%20swing-75min.pdf)"

Comment: Is there Oracle or system specific guidelines that support this statement? That label + separator should be preferred over group boxing? JGoodies is just *one* company implementing Java.

Comment: @Kissaki I mentioned it was a good practice, not an official guideline from anyone. The fact is, with Swing layouts managers system, you CANNOT align components across 2 panels. Hence using borders means losing alignment of wour components.

Answer (score 5):

A Group box is just a set of 'logically grouped widgets'.
This in the swing world is a `JPanel`.

Add your widgets to a `JPanel`.

Set its border type to 'Titled Border' and give the title, same as the name of the VB6 'frame'.

Voila. You have your group box.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a quote from the JRadioButton javadocs since you brought up radio buttons.

> An implementation of a radio button -- an item that can be selected or deselected, and which displays its state to the user. Used with a ButtonGroup object to create a group of buttons in which only one button at a time can be selected. (Create a ButtonGroup object and use its add method to include the JRadioButton objects in the group.)
>
> Note: The ButtonGroup object is a logical grouping -- not a physical grouping. To create a button panel, you should still create a JPanel or similar container-object and add a Border to it to set it off from surrounding components.

Comment: Thanks, but as you correctly point out, my main intent was the "visual" aspect.

Answer (score 1):

Not AFAIK, at least not with standard swing widgets.

In VB you have a group widget, which is essentially a panel + border.

In Swing you have a JPanel which is the container widget, and you create and set a border object on it only if you need one. One can argue that in a way that is more elegant since you don't pay for something you don't use (e.g., border)

Answer (score 1):

As David Koelle mentioned about setting up border through java code, you can also achieve similar result in designer mode.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I'm responding based on the Uri's comment which explaind what the OP meant by `Group Box`:

> Uri: I think he means the control group you see in many dialog boxes, where you have a square around a bunch of widgets such as radio buttons, for example.

As far as I know, every `JComponent` can set a border for itself, so you don't need a second panel.

Comment: I want to have a border around a number of JComponents .. also, having just one element in a group box is usually bad practice.

Comment: You can add more than one component in a JPanel .