# Create a Titled border with the title as a JCheckBox

Tags: java, swing

I want to create a titled border with the title as a CheckBox.

[image: this is a kind of border i am looking for]

How do i do that?

Comment: what have u done so far? Can u show your code?

Comment: Take a look on this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/431654/is-there-a-group-box-equivalent-in-java-swing

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This tutorial is exactly what you need: [CLICK](https://web.archive.org/web/20170913154430/http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t33048.html)

Unfortunately the images are no longer online, but you can launch the Webstart application.

Comment: Link Dead - Any chance of an alternate or webarchive ?

Answer (score 2):

Credit to JavaLobby and Stephan for the basis of this answer.

However, this is a cut-down example that provides a simple implementation of a `TitledBorder` with a `JCheckBox`:

```
public class CheckBoxTitledBorder extends AbstractBorder {

  private final TitledBorder _parent;
  private final JCheckBox _checkBox;

  public CheckBoxTitledBorder(String title, boolean selected) {
    _parent = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(title);
    _checkBox = new JCheckBox(title, selected);
    _checkBox.setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.LEFT);
  }

  public boolean isSelected() {
    return _checkBox.isSelected();
  }

  public void addActionListener(ActionListener listener) {
    _checkBox.addActionListener(listener);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isBorderOpaque() {
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public void paintBorder(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y, int width, int height) {
    Insets borderInsets = _parent.getBorderInsets(c);
    Insets insets = getBorderInsets(c);
    int temp = (insets.top - borderInsets.top) / 2;
    _parent.paintBorder(c, g, x, y + temp, width, height - temp);
    Dimension size = _checkBox.getPreferredSize();
    final Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(5, 0, size.width, size.height);

    final Container container = (Container) c;
    container.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
      private void dispatchEvent(MouseEvent me) {
        if (rectangle.contains(me.getX(), me.getY())) {
          Point pt = me.getPoint();
          pt.translate(-5, 0);
          _checkBox.setBounds(rectangle);
          _checkBox.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent(_checkBox, me.getID(),
            me.getWhen(), me.getModifiers(), pt.x, pt.y, me.getClickCount(), me.isPopupTrigger(), me.getButton()));
          if (!_checkBox.isValid()) {
            container.repaint();
          }
        }
      }

      public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) {
        dispatchEvent(me);
      }

      public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent me) {
        dispatchEvent(me);
      }
    });
    SwingUtilities.paintComponent(g, _checkBox, container, rectangle);
  }

  @Override
  public Insets getBorderInsets(Component c) {
    Insets insets = _parent.getBorderInsets(c);
    insets.top = Math.max(insets.top, _checkBox.getPreferredSize().height);
    return insets;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also found [this example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-Components/ComponentTitledPaneExample2.htm).

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;

/**
 * @version 1.0 08/12/99
 */
public class CompTitledPaneExample2 extends JFrame {

    public CompTitledPaneExample2() {
        super("CompTitledPaneExample2");
        JCheckBox title = new JCheckBox("Title");
        title.setSelected(true);
        final CompTitledPane p1 = new CompTitledPane(title);
        title.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
                p1.setEnabled(e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED);
            }
        });
        APanel p2 = new APanel();
        p1.setTransmittingAllowed(true);
        p1.setTransmitter(p2);
        p1.getContentPane().add(p2);
        getContentPane().add(p1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    class APanel extends JPanel implements StateTransmitter {

        JButton button;

        JTextField textField;

        APanel() {
            button = new JButton("abc");
            button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    System.out.println("Ouch!");
                }
            });
            textField = new JTextField(10);
            textField.setText("text");
            add(button, BorderLayout.NORTH);
            add(textField, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        }

        public void setChildrenEnabled(boolean enable) {
            button.setEnabled(enable);
            textField.setEnabled(enable);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel");
        } catch (Exception evt) {
        }

        CompTitledPaneExample2 frame = new CompTitledPaneExample2();
        frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        frame.setSize(280, 110);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class CompTitledPane extends JPanel {

    protected CompTitledBorder border;

    protected JComponent component;

    protected JPanel panel;

    protected boolean transmittingAllowed;

    protected StateTransmitter transmitter;

    public CompTitledPane() {
        this(new JLabel("Title"));
    // debug
        // JLabel label = (JLabel)getTitleComponent();
        // label.setOpaque(true);
        // label.setBackground(Color.yellow);
    }

    public CompTitledPane(JComponent component) {
        this.component = component;
        border = new CompTitledBorder(component);
        setBorder(border);
        panel = new JPanel();
        setLayout(null);
        add(component);
        add(panel);
        transmittingAllowed = false;
        transmitter = null;
    }

    public JComponent getTitleComponent() {
        return component;
    }

    public void setTitleComponent(JComponent newComponent) {
        remove(component);
        add(newComponent);
        border.setTitleComponent(newComponent);
        component = newComponent;
    }

    public JPanel getContentPane() {
        return panel;
    }

    public void doLayout() {
        Insets insets = getInsets();
        Rectangle rect = getBounds();
        rect.x = 0;
        rect.y = 0;

        Rectangle compR = border.getComponentRect(rect, insets);
        component.setBounds(compR);
        rect.x += insets.left;
        rect.y += insets.top;
        rect.width -= insets.left + insets.right;
        rect.height -= insets.top + insets.bottom;
        panel.setBounds(rect);
    }

    public void setTransmittingAllowed(boolean enable) {
        transmittingAllowed = enable;
    }

    public boolean getTransmittingAllowed() {
        return transmittingAllowed;
    }

    public void setTransmitter(StateTransmitter transmitter) {
        this.transmitter = transmitter;
    }

    public StateTransmitter getTransmitter() {
        return transmitter;
    }

    public void setEnabled(boolean enable) {
        super.setEnabled(enable);
        if (transmittingAllowed && transmitter != null) {
            transmitter.setChildrenEnabled(enable);
        }
    }

}

interface StateTransmitter {

    public void setChildrenEnabled(boolean enable);

}

class CompTitledBorder extends TitledBorder {

    protected JComponent component;

    public CompTitledBorder(JComponent component) {
        this(null, component, LEFT, TOP);
    }

    public CompTitledBorder(Border border) {
        this(border, null, LEFT, TOP);
    }

    public CompTitledBorder(Border border, JComponent component) {
        this(border, component, LEFT, TOP);
    }

    public CompTitledBorder(Border border, JComponent component,
            int titleJustification, int titlePosition) {
        super(border, null, titleJustification, titlePosition, null, null);
        this.component = component;
        if (border == null) {
            this.border = super.getBorder();
        }
    }

    public void paintBorder(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y, int width,
            int height) {
        Rectangle borderR = new Rectangle(x + EDGE_SPACING, y + EDGE_SPACING,
                width - (EDGE_SPACING * 2), height - (EDGE_SPACING * 2));
        Insets borderInsets;
        if (border != null) {
            borderInsets = border.getBorderInsets(c);
        } else {
            borderInsets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0);
        }

        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);
        Insets insets = getBorderInsets(c);
        Rectangle compR = getComponentRect(rect, insets);
        int diff;
        switch (titlePosition) {
            case ABOVE_TOP:
                diff = compR.height + TEXT_SPACING;
                borderR.y += diff;
                borderR.height -= diff;
                break;
            case TOP:
            case DEFAULT_POSITION:
                diff = insets.top / 2 - borderInsets.top - EDGE_SPACING;
                borderR.y += diff;
                borderR.height -= diff;
                break;
            case BELOW_TOP:
            case ABOVE_BOTTOM:
                break;
            case BOTTOM:
                diff = insets.bottom / 2 - borderInsets.bottom - EDGE_SPACING;
                borderR.height -= diff;
                break;
            case BELOW_BOTTOM:
                diff = compR.height + TEXT_SPACING;
                borderR.height -= diff;
                break;
        }
        border.paintBorder(c, g, borderR.x, borderR.y, borderR.width,
                borderR.height);
        Color col = g.getColor();
        g.setColor(c.getBackground());
        g.fillRect(compR.x, compR.y, compR.width, compR.height);
        g.setColor(col);
        component.repaint();
    }

    public Insets getBorderInsets(Component c, Insets insets) {
        Insets borderInsets;
        if (border != null) {
            borderInsets = border.getBorderInsets(c);
        } else {
            borderInsets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0);
        }
        insets.top = EDGE_SPACING + TEXT_SPACING + borderInsets.top;
        insets.right = EDGE_SPACING + TEXT_SPACING + borderInsets.right;
        insets.bottom = EDGE_SPACING + TEXT_SPACING + borderInsets.bottom;
        insets.left = EDGE_SPACING + TEXT_SPACING + borderInsets.left;

        if (c == null || component == null) {
            return insets;
        }

        int compHeight = 0;
        if (component != null) {
            compHeight = component.getPreferredSize().height;
        }

        switch (titlePosition) {
            case ABOVE_TOP:
                insets.top += compHeight + TEXT_SPACING;
                break;
            case TOP:
            case DEFAULT_POSITION:
                insets.top += Math.max(compHeight, borderInsets.top)
                        - borderInsets.top;
                break;
            case BELOW_TOP:
                insets.top += compHeight + TEXT_SPACING;
                break;
            case ABOVE_BOTTOM:
                insets.bottom += compHeight + TEXT_SPACING;
                break;
            case BOTTOM:
                insets.bottom += Math.max(compHeight, borderInsets.bottom)
                        - borderInsets.bottom;
                break;
            case BELOW_BOTTOM:
                insets.bottom += compHeight + TEXT_SPACING;
                break;
        }
        return insets;
    }

    public JComponent getTitleComponent() {
        return component;
    }

    public void setTitleComponent(JComponent component) {
        this.component = component;
    }

    public Rectangle getComponentRect(Rectangle rect, Insets borderInsets) {
        Dimension compD = component.getPreferredSize();
        Rectangle compR = new Rectangle(0, 0, compD.width, compD.height);
        switch (titlePosition) {
            case ABOVE_TOP:
                compR.y = EDGE_SPACING;
                break;
            case TOP:
            case DEFAULT_POSITION:
                compR.y = EDGE_SPACING
                        + (borderInsets.top - EDGE_SPACING - TEXT_SPACING - compD.height)
                        / 2;
                break;
            case BELOW_TOP:
                compR.y = borderInsets.top - compD.height - TEXT_SPACING;
                break;
            case ABOVE_BOTTOM:
                compR.y = rect.height - borderInsets.bottom + TEXT_SPACING;
                break;
            case BOTTOM:
                compR.y = rect.height
                        - borderInsets.bottom
                        + TEXT_SPACING
                        + (borderInsets.bottom - EDGE_SPACING - TEXT_SPACING - compD.height)
                        / 2;
                break;
            case BELOW_BOTTOM:
                compR.y = rect.height - compD.height - EDGE_SPACING;
                break;
        }
        switch (titleJustification) {
            case LEFT:
            case DEFAULT_JUSTIFICATION:
                compR.x = TEXT_INSET_H + borderInsets.left;
                break;
            case RIGHT:
                compR.x = rect.width - borderInsets.right - TEXT_INSET_H
                        - compR.width;
                break;
            case CENTER:
                compR.x = (rect.width - compR.width) / 2;
                break;
        }
        return compR;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution is to just make your checkbox overlap the other panel with the titled border, with the title text as just " ".

You can do this by having the bordered JPanel and the JCheckBox in the same GridBagLayout cell for instance. Just make sure that you add the checkbox first, and give it different GridBagConstraints Insets than your bordered JPanel so that it lines up.

I set the title text to " " so that it automatically adjusts the contents and stuff to make room for the title as it normally would, but you could just as easily use a different border and size everything up yourself.